# Can not bind distinct to drop down control

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, data-binding, entity

My application is showing this error below:

**Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported**

Due to the fact that I am trying to bind my drop down control to this LINQ statement. 
Check below for my code;

```
 using (AdventureWorksEntities dw = new AdventureWorksEntities())
        {
            ddlCon.DataSource = (from em in dw.Employees
                       select new { em.Title, em.EmployeeID }).Distinct().OrderBy(name => name);
            ;


            ddlCon.DataTextField = "Title";
            ddlCon.DataValueField = "EmployeeID";
            ddlCon.DataBind();
        }
```

NB: Please explain well in your answers why this error and the solution to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938371/data-binding-directly-to-a-store-query-dbset-dbquery-dbsqlquery-is-not-suppo), you need to use `ToList()`, as you can't bind directly to a query result.

That being said, I also suspect your `OrderBy` is incorrect.  This should likely be:

```
 ddlCon.DataSource = (from em in dw.Employees
                      select new { em.Title, em.EmployeeID })
                    .Distinct()
                    .OrderBy(emp => emp.Title)  // Pick Title or EmployeeID here
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute your query and bring results from database to memory. Only objects in memory could be used as data source. This could be achieved by applying `ToList` to your query:

```
ddlCon.DataSource = (from em in dw.Employees
                     select new { em.Title, em.EmployeeID })
                    .Distinct()
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Title)
                    .ToList();
```