# Saving data using Entity Framework 5.0 and xtragrid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xtragrid

I am using xtragrid to save, load and modify data. Now after switching to EF5, it just doesn't work. Tried changing my code to `local` and to `tobindinglist`, but nothing gets changed in the database. Any suggestions?

```
public partial class formKonstruksiyon : Form
{
    public Tank_Analizor_DBEntities db;

    public formKonstruksiyon()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        db = new Tank_Analizor_DBEntities();
    }

    private void formKonstruksiyon_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        konstruksiyonBindingSource.DataSource = db.Konstruksiyon.Local.ToBindingList();
        gridControl1.DataSource = konstruksiyonBindingSource.DataSource;
    }

    private void barButtonItemSave_ItemClick(object sender,
      DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            LibStatic.ShowSuccessMessage();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LibStatic.ShowErrorMessage(ex);
        }
    }

    private void silToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gridView1.DeleteRow(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle);
    }
}
```

Some updates after changing:

```
 konstruksiyonBindingSource.DataSource = db.Konstruksiyon.ToList();

 private void barButtonItemSave_ItemClick(object sender, 
   DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            LibStatic.GridPostPendingRow(gridView1);

            try
            {
                konstruksiyonBindingSource.DataSource = db.Konstruksiyon.Local.ToBindingList();

                db.SaveChanges();
                LibStatic.ShowSuccessMessage();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LibStatic.ShowErrorMessage(ex);
            } 
        }
```

It sort of saves: it doesn't save if I add only one entry, yet it saves if I add two. How is that even possible?

Comment: Have you tried it with just `db.Konstruksiyon` ?

Comment: yeah,i get an error saying "Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported.",however that was the method i used all the time up until ef5

Comment: A simple google search on your error message gave me [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938371/data-binding-directly-to-a-store-query-dbset-dbquery-dbsqlquery-is-not-suppo). Have you looked into it?

Comment: Yeah,thats what i did in the first place,tried binding the local datasource.Yet the problem is the bindlingsource does not persist.

Comment: Can you try `db.Konstruksiyon.ToList();` as long as the context stays alive for the time the grid is displayed the entities should have change tracking.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the entity to your context, or in case your're performing a update, attach the entity and set the State property to modified:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=619

Answer (score 0):

Try letting the datasource be an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.103%29.aspx),  instead of a List:

```
konstruksiyonBindingSource.DataSource = db.Konstruksiyon.Local;
```

It knows *when* the changes occour, and therefore should be better suited for changetracking