# ADO.Net Data Binding Error to ASP DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, data-binding

**Error Message:**

> Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is
>   not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by
>   calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind
>   to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList().

Has something changed in VS2012 - I've used this same strategy before?

**Data Layer code to retrieve data:**

```
namespace DataLibrary
{
    public class DLgetMasterData
    {
        POLLINATORSEntities db = new POLLINATORSEntities();

        public IEnumerable<string> getSoil()
        {
            var soilList = from SOTYPE in db.SOTYPEs
                           orderby SOTYPE.SOTYPE_DESC ascending
                           select SOTYPE.SOTYPE_DESC;
            return soilList;
        }
```

**Code behind page in UI:**

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                BLgetMasterData obj = new BLgetMasterData();

                var soilList = obj.getSoil();
                Soil.DataSource = soilList;
                Soil.DataBind();
                Soil.Items.Insert(0, "Any");
                Soil.SelectedValue = "Any";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind to a query, which is usually some `IQueryable` (at least not anymore, not sure if you could in the past), so you need to bind to some local collection.

> ```
> var soilList = from SOTYPE in db.SOTYPEs
>                        orderby SOTYPE.SOTYPE_DESC ascending
>                        select SOTYPE.SOTYPE_DESC;
> ```

`soilList` represents a query that will be sent to a database, so if you add `ToList()` at the end, that will create a local collection of the results for your query, and you will be able to bind to that.

See: [Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938371/data-binding-directly-to-a-store-query-dbset-dbquery-dbsqlquery-is-not-suppo)